# Word for "no longer dry"

Tags: single-word-requests

In response to someone elsewhere eggcoining the phrase "whet one's whistle," I just found myself wanting to write that

> An appetite is *whetted* until it is sharp; but a whistle is *wetted* until it is ____.

I feel like the word-to-go-in-the-blank is right on the tip of my tongue, but I can't quite place it.

What is it that a sip of water does to one's lips, either as a verb or as an adjective?

- a whistle is wetted until it is *damp*?
- a whistle is wetted until it is *moist*?
- a whistle is wetted until it is *moistened*?
- a whistle is wetted until it is *satiated*?
- a whistle is wetted until it is *quenched*?
- a whistle is wetted until it is *wet*?
- a whistle is wetted until it is *wetted*?

I disqualify the last two on the grounds of tautology: "wetted until it is wet" doesn't work for me.

Besides not sounding quite right to the ear, neither "satiated" nor "quenched" works semantically — if you merely wet your whistle, you don't go all the way toward quenching your thirst.

"Damp" and "moist" both kinda work, but neither is very pleasant.

Is there a word for essentially "no longer bone-dry" that I'm missing?

Comment: I vote for *quenched*, since one of the definitions of the idiom is *to quench one's thirst*. If you want something pithy, I'd go with *tuned* to make a play on *whistle* and oppose *sharp*.

Comment: @JasonBassford: Maybe one of us is confused, but I think you're agreeing with what I wrote: "wet your whistle", "whet your appetite". I've already connected "whet" with "sharp" (i.e. "whetted"); I am now attempting to connect "wet" with a word that means "no longer dry" (i.e. "wetted"). I am 100% definitely asking for a word that means "no longer dry."

Comment: @jxh: Besides not sounding quite right to the ear, "quenched" doesn't work semantically — if you merely wet your whistle, you don't go all the way toward quenching your thirst. However, I do kind of like "tuned", even though it answers only metaphorically. :)  (Similarly: "wet your whistle until it is audible"?)

Comment: @JasonBassford: I guess there is. To me, "whet one's appetite" means "take the existing hunger level and increase it until it is relatively high", whereas "wet one's whistle" means "take the existing state of thirst and decrease it just a small amount." I would use the idioms as follows— The drink did not entirely _quench my thirst_; it merely _wet my whistle_. The meal did not _satiate my hunger_; in fact it had the opposite effect — it _whetted my appetite_ and caused me to be hungrier than before.

Comment: I am far more confused now than I was before, and have even less of an idea of what you want.  You seem to be arguing against some of your own suggestions (*satiated*), you seem to like others that have nothing to do with moisture (*tuned* and *audible*), and I keep being side tracked by your analogy to a *whetted* appetite that is *sharp* (which is more extreme than either "a bit less dull" or "a little hungry or thirsty").

Comment: ...a whistle is wet until it is [**unparched**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/unparched).

Comment: @J.R. (and @jxh) should be posting answers to collect Internet points! :)

Comment: An appetite is whetted until it is keen; but a whistle is wetted until it is weaned.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're looking for something clever or simply something that will fill in the blank, but if the latter, I would suggest ***hydrated*** (or, as my kids used to say, *hyderated*.)  From the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[hydrate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hydrate)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Cause to absorb water.
>
>    *‘a powerful moisturizer that hydrates the skin for up to twelve hours’*

Now, while sipping some water would not *technically* hyrdrate your lips, but given that *one's whistle* is a little more abstract (or, I suppose, the space between your lips when whistling), I think it suits.

In your example, it would be:

> *An appetite is whetted until it is sharp; but a whistle is wetted until it is **hydrated**.*

Comment: That's too Latinate for my taste (compared to the Anglo-Saxon _wet_, _whet_, _sharp_, etc), so not accepted, but upvoted. :)

Comment: ODO says it comes from Greek: _Origin:  Early 19th century: coined in French from Greek hudōr ‘water’._  WebMD lists the _[Top 10 Ways to Stay Hydrated](https://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/features/top-10-ways-to-stay-hydrated)_ and FamilyDoctor.org has an article on _[Hydration: Why It’s So Important](https://familydoctor.org/hydration-why-its-so-important/)_.  Children's Health has an article on _[The importance of hydration for young athletes](https://www.childrens.com/health-wellness/the-importance-of-hydration-for-young-athletes)_.  Hydrate, in this context, seems fairly common.

Comment: Other than _wet_ or _moisten_, I'm not sure there's much else to choose from.  Thanks for the upvote, however.

Answer (score 1):

From your question and your comments on other answers, I think you may want a word like **slake**.

> [**slake**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slake) ***(transitive verb)***
>
> 1 *archaic* to lessen the force of; moderate
>
> 2
>   **satisfy, quench**
>
> ***slake your thirst***
>
> ***will slake your curiosity***
>
> 3
>   to cause (a substance, such as lime) to heat and crumble by treatment with water; hydrate

**Slake** has a slightly archaic feel to it which might give your coinage the sound of something like a long-established proverb. (It's a proper [Old English word](https://www.etymonline.com/word/slake#etymonline_v_23637) and a cognate of *slack*.)

You might say in your sentence (or *bon mot* or whatever it is!):

> An appetite whetted's **a sharp bellyache**, but a whistle is wet **only when it is *slaked***.

Personally, I prefer the suggestion I offered in the comments previously, but that may be going off script a little too much:

> An appetite's whetted **until it's acute** but a whistle is wet **with a brew down the chute**.

Comment: User Phil Sweet also has a lovely couplet in the comments on the question itself, which has all the sound of a proper proverbial warning passed down the generations.

Comment: Both "slake" and "quench" have the trouble mentioned in the question that they connote "satiated to fullness," whereas a wetted whistle is only a little bit wet; e.g., a single sip of water may wet your whistle but does not "slake" it. (So a whistle _isn't_ wetted _only_ when it is slaked — often you wet your whistle _without_ slaking it.) I do like your second rhyme ("a brew down the chute"); not really an answer but very clever and reasonably accurate. :)

Comment: For the actual answer to my question, I still prefer J.R.'s "unparched" above all the other contenders so far. But it wasn't expressed as an answer (just a comment), and most damningly, it didn't come as a rhyming couplet. Apparently that's a requirement now. ;)

Comment: And there was me thinking you'd be happy with a Germanic verb that means _hydrate_. But a legititmate objection - I see the problem indeed. If I may: _An appetite whetted's a sharp bellyache, but is whistle is wet whether dampened or slaked._ Or you could do something with _a drop_.

Comment: or to get a little judgemental on the booze: _a whistle is wetted until it is slaked._